# Relationship between nerves and axons

Tags: neuroscience, physiology, neurophysiology, peripheral-nervous-system, touch

I just wanted to get a realistic viewpoint of our nervous system. I understand arteries and veins, but I wanted to know how similar our nervous system is to that?

I understand we have neurons (please correct me if I am wrong) all over the surface of body. Whenever we feel a touch a neuron fires a response, and that response travels through axons (myelin sheath).

My main question is what a nerve exactly is. Is it a long axon? How many axons (same thing as neuron body?) are in a nerve? I am sure it depends on different nerves.

Comment: I vote to re-open - this question is not too broad. On the contrary, it is a set of highly specific questions, basically boiling down to terminology. I edited the question previously when the close-votes were already pouring in, and hence I vote now to re-open without editing any further. I think it is fine as is. Furthermore, there is background info, so there is no ground to 'leave-close' due to homework :-)

Comment: I forgot to message you, but I edited your question to make it more compatible with Biology Stack Exchange. At Biology we like clear questions. Nice question +1

Comment: Chris, this was my first question on this website. I only knew of one rule and that was to be as specific as possible. I tried. I am not very familiar with the format of this website so I am not sure what "close-votes" or "re-open" you were talking about. I barely found out that my question was answered :) which I really appreciate.

Comment: @ChrisStronks I see a number 4 next to my question. What does that mean? Net positive votes I got?
Also, can anyone edit my question? Or do you run this website?

Comment: The close-vote and re-open comments were directed to others that close-voted this question. It may help you to read through the help site and see what a good question looks like and what can happen when people not agree with the question content.

Comment: The +4 means that 4 folks liked your question. I can edit it among many others. I am just one participant among many others with enough reputation to edit questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will go through your list of questions below:

- *I wanted to know how similar is our nervous system to [the circulatory system]?*
  **They are very different, but as in every comparison of very complex systems, there is some overlap**. The circulatory system carries fluids, the nervous system electrical signals so they are functionally not alike. However, both systems run throughout the body and have a more or less central control unit (the brain and heart respectively). So there is a structural similarity. I reckon they are as much alike as a city's sewer system and electricity grid.
- *I understand we have neurons (please correct me if I am wrong) all over the surface of body.*
  **That is correct**
- *Whenever we feel a touch (stimulus arises) a neuron fires a response, and that response travels through axons (myelin sheath).*
  **Tactile stimulation may result in firing of one or more neurons**, dependent on the intensity of the stimulus. Larger stimuli will, obviously, recruit more fibers. Stronger stimuli will evoke stronger responses (increased firing). **Axons indeed conduct the neuronal responses**, like an electrical wire conducts electrical current. Longer axons are often myelinated (insulated). Not all neurons related to touch are myelinated, however.
- *So my main question is that what exactly is a nerve?*
  **A nerve is a bundle of axons** that carry related functional information. Typically, nerves conduct information originating from locations closely located together in the body, and generally they convey this information to a localized spot in the body as well. For example, the optic nerve carries information from the photoreceptors (related information) from the retina (localized source) to the brainstem (localized target).
- *Is [a nerve] a long axon?*
  **A nerve contains many axons**. 'Long' or 'short' is rather subjective.
- *How many axons (same thing as neuron body?) are in a nerve? I am sure it depends on different nerves.*
  **Neuronal cell bodies are typically located outside a nerve**. **Nerves contain varying numbers of fibers.** For example, the auditory nerve harbors the axons of the spiral ganglion cells that transmit auditory information from the inner ear to the brain. It contains between 31k - 32k (myelinated) fibers in normal-hearing humans ([Spoendlin & Schrott, 1989](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2613564)). In contrast, the optic nerve, which carries visual information from the retina to the brain, contains some 1.3 million (myelinated) fibers in young human adults ([Jonas et al., 1992](http://www.iovs.org/content/33/6/2012.full.pdf))

<sup>**References**

**-** [Jonas et al., *IOVS* 1992;**33**:2012-8](http://www.iovs.org/content/33/6/2012.full.pdf)

**-** [Spoendlin & Schrott, *Hear Res* 1989;**43**:25-38](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2613564)</sup>

Comment: Chris, I deleted my answer. Plus this is the source of the picture:http://dtc.pima.edu/blc/182/lesson12/12step6/12step6page1.html

Comment: Thank you, Chris for answering the question. I really appreciate it.